# easiest way to deploy sailsjs API

Tags: azure, sails.js

I am currently working sailsjs and how can i deploy it on azure?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Specifically: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*"  Asking for a cloud computing platform recommendation is equivalent to asking for a tool recommendation. Also: "easiest" is a matter of opinion, and on that help page, "*Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be put on hold by the community until they are improved.*"

Comment: You down voted my question for just this as I can clearly improved my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a blog post a couple of months ago which gives the steps needed to deploy to azure:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-sails/

Comment: The question itself is off-topic. And posting link-only answers (such as links to how-to's) doesn't really help. Especially when the OP is asking for hosting recommendations based on price, as well as "easiest" way (which is subjective).

Comment: You are down voting a link to a tutorial produced by Microsoft in March this year specifically for lifting a sails application and you believe it doesn't really help? I completely disagree and I will not be regurgitating information to satisfy your view of rules when it can come directly from the source with the knowledge that is needed. I see 2 question marks in the original post. I have answered 1 of them, I can not answer the other.